# MVC Form with Sitecore File Post through Form returns Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, sitecore, httppostedfilebase

For the possible duplicate, I already know how to preview my image before uploading it, my issue as detailed below is that when I submit the Form, the image is being received as null.

I am trying to submit a form to an MVC controller that should submit a model, a string, and an Image File,

I made sure that the input has the same name as the parameter within the controller

Following is the Form Initialization code

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName,
new
{
    calendar = System.Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["calendar"]),
    ID = System.Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["id"])
},
    FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

//Model Input

<input style="opacity: 0;" name="EventImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" id="ImageUpload" onchange="readURL(this);" />
}
```

And the Controller Header

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult AddEvent(Event model, string calendar, HttpPostedFileBase EventImage)
```

The EventImage Parameter is being returned null and I can't seem to figure out why.
I thought that the ID might be causing the problem so I changed the name attribute to ImageUpload as well as the Parameter within the controller but to no avail as the value is still null.

Additional Info: when a User uploads an image, I let them preview it in an Image box, could that be causing it?

Thanks,

Update:

Here is the code for the readURL function

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var ImageCorrect = false;
    var file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();        
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        // Concatenate our HTML image info 
        var ext = file.name.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
        switch (ext) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'JPG':
            case 'JPEG':
                {
                    if ((Math.round(file.size / 1024)) > 500) {
                        alert('Image is too Large');
                    }
                    else {
                        var image = new Image();
                        image.src = e.target.result;
                        image.onload = function () {
                            var width = parseInt(image.width);
                            if (width <= 500) {
                                $('#previewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                                $('#previewImage').show();                                   

                            }
                            else {
                                alert('Image width exceeds maximum width');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert('Image type not allowed')
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your `readURL(this)` function doing? If you just making a normal submit, then the code you have shown will bind correctly to you parameter `EventImage` if the file input has `name="EventImage"` (the `id` attribute has nothing to do with posted values and is only relevant for javascript/css selectors)

Comment: It's to read the file into an img tag in order to create a preview

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added it now

Comment: That code looks OK, but just to be sure, temporary remove `onchange="readURL(this);` and test that the file is being uploaded and bound correctly.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke I'll try it out and post the results

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right you are trying to submit a file from your form to your controller and you get null in the controller.

I did this before, check the following:

cshtml (you can add your attributes to event image like JS call...etc ):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("EventImage")<br>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventImage, new { type = "file" })
</div>
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Event Image")]
public HttpPostedFileBase EventImage { get; set; }
```

Controller Signature:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddEvent(Event model)
```

Catching the Image field:

```
if (model.EventImage != null && model.EventImage.ContentLength > 0)
{
     var fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.EventImage.FileName);
     var tempPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/uploads");
     var path = Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName);
     if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
           Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

     model.EventImage.SaveAs(path);

     Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions();
     options.FileBased = false;
     options.IncludeExtensionInItemName = false;
     options.KeepExisting = false;
     options.Versioned = false;
     options.Destination = "/sitecore/media library/Images/" + ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(Path.GetFileName(path));
     options.Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(MasterDatabase);

      // Now create the file
      Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
      MediaItem mediaItem = creator.CreateFromFile(path, options);

      ImageField _eventImage = (ImageField)_event.Fields[EventImage];
                            _eventImage.MediaID = mediaItem.ID;
                            PublishItem(mediaItem);
}
```

Comment: This seemed pretty close, I'm not sure about saving the file to the server beforehand though. You can use `creator.CreateFromStream(file.InputStream, fileName, options)` instead